# Problem of Core Data FetchRequest() in SwiftUI customized action

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've customed an acting function fetch() while tapping FETCH Button.

Why did I always get an "empty" output while executing this function even I have something in my database?

Here is my View struct:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Entity.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [],
        animation: .default)
    private var entities: FetchedResults<Entity>

    private func fetch(){
        let fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Entity>(entity: Entity.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
        if(fetchRequest.wrappedValue.isEmpty){
            print("empty")
        }
    }

    @State var attr = ""
    
    private func add(){
        let newEn = Entity(context: viewContext)
        newEn.attribute = self.attr
        newEn.id = UUID()
        do{
            try viewContext.save()
            print("SAVED")
        } catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(
                action: fetch,
                label: { Text("FETCH") }
            )
            List {
                ForEach(entities) { item in
                    Text("\(item.attribute)")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text("\(item.id)")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
            TextField("attribute", text: $attr)
            Button(
                action: add,
                label: { Text("ADD") }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNIwT.png)

[user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIb4l.png)

Comment: You have 2 fetch requests when you only need one. I assume you really want to work with the `entities` property that should refresh automatically. Also in the fetch function you never execute the fetch request

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Thanks for answering. I just want to show that I did have something in my database so I used `@FetchRequest()` to perform a List. Also I wonder how I could execute fetch request in `fetch()` function.

Comment: You call [fetch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506672-fetch) using your `viewContext`